# Term for a "rooted" directional graph?

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, terminology

Consider an acyclic directed graph in which a traversal from any node in the graph must eventually end at some terminal node *R*.  Borrowing from tree-based vocabulary, I would tend call this the "root" of the graph, since all traversals eventually terminate there.  However, the term "[rooted graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RootedGraph.html)" seems to already be in use for something else.

Is there a term I can use to describe this property?  The best way I can describe the graph at present is a "multi-parented directed tree" -- all nodes point toward the root, but, unlike a directed tree, nodes may have more than one parent. I don't like this terminology, though, as it seems like an abuse of the term "tree".

I considered "hierarchical graph", but a node can have more than one outgoing vertex, so I think that may disqualify it from being hierarchical.

Comment: If it's a tree, call such a directed tree with each edge oriented towards the root an **inverse pine**.  (A **pine** is a tree with every edge is oriented *away* from the root.)  If it's not a tree, then I have no idea.

Comment: @ZsbánAmbrus: Do you have a source for the term "pine"?

Comment: @JeffE: Hmm, can I change my reply then?  Call such a tree an **inverse arborescence**, the source being Lovász, Combinatorial Problems and Exercises.

Comment: A rooted graph is usually identified with a directed graph (with the root being the 'source'). It is perfectly reasonable to treat the root as the 'sink' instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if these graphs have a common name. But I think, one would call vertices with no outgoing edge rather a **sink** than a **root**.

This [paper](http://www.mth.msu.edu/~sagan/Papers/Old/sao.pdf) studies acyclic orientations of grid graphs. They call an orientation, which would correspond to the graphs you consider, *acyclic orientations with a unique sink*.

Comment: And if you felt like going the other way, a vertex with only outgoing edges is a source.